# Vuejs - Render raw html links to <router-link>

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

I;m new to VueJS and I'm making some weird experiments. I build a backend service using python/flask and this backend provide me a string of html code with many  tags inside, I want to render this inside my Vue app, I have a method for calling the backend that looks like this:

```
async execute (method, resource, data) {
    return client({
      method,
      url: resource,
      data: data
    }).then(async req => {
      return req.data.html
    })
  },
  callBack (id) {
    console.log(id)
    return this.execute('post', '/content/', {body: { 'id': id }})
  }
```

And in the .vue file I have:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      launch: [],
      html: 'none',
      page: this.$route.params.article
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    console.log('beforeee')
    this.html = api.callBack(this.page)
  },
  methods: {
    async launch () {
      this.launch = ''
      this.html = await api.callBack(this.page)
    }
  }
}
```

so when I call the launch function it populates this.html, and this html variable lives in a v-html.Everything seems to work i get the html and render it in de container but the links are broken, the links should point at the same app something like #/test/linkvalue, but as they are  tags, and in vue you have to use  they doesn't work.

There is a way to achieve this "dynamic re route" or I'm doing something too weird? 
The links are plenty, since they are scraped from the web, so manually parsing is not an option.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1Lbro0q/2/)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Just out of curiosity: if you have a Vue app, why  would you want to generate html on the server?

Comment: Hi! I'm just performing some experiments. The idea is to use the server to scrap the web do some preprocessing, storage and return the html or something to the app to render.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you shouldn't return the raw html. Just return the paths for the routes and then loop the paths and create links that way.

You can use the `v-html` vue directive to output raw html.

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/66262/

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rawhtml: "<h1 style='color: red;'>Hi, I am raw html.</h1>"
  },
  methods: {    
  }
})


<div id="app">
  <div v-html="rawhtml"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have something like that, but the links inside the html are dead. according to the documentations they should be <router-link>. To be clear the html works and renders just fine, but the links, the <a href>  tags inside, are the thing that doesn't work.

Comment: @RolandDeschain can you create a js fiddle to replicate it?

Comment: Hi, I did this https://jsfiddle.net/u1Lbro0q/ now image in the call launch the html variable gets populated with many link pointing at #/route/x that is defined in the vue router, but the links doesnt work I click on them and nothing.

Comment: Well in fact the links do change the url in the browser, but the page doesn't reload nor the view reload accordingly with the new url.

Comment: @RolandDeschain if you change your html link to http://google.com, it works fine. Can you add your vue router code to your question?

Comment: Hi, I update it https://jsfiddle.net/u1Lbro0q/2/ . I think this illustrate my point , when I hit the launch button, it generates a new link, clicking the link should take me to the route defined in the router, and show the message in the template. But it does nothing.

Comment: @RolandDeschain why do you have the pound symbol in your route? That seems to be breaking it.

Comment: Mmmm If it remove it it tries to redirect to jsfiddle/sub1/(random string) and then it breaks.